# Python - How Should We Name Property Functions According To PEP8

Tags: python, properties, pep8, python-3.10

So I have a class with some properties

```
class Card:

    __CARDS = ["3"]
    __COLORS = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow"]

    @property
    def CARDS(self) -> list:
        return self.__CARDS
    
    @property
    def COLORS(self) -> list:
        return self.__COLORS
```

So As __CARDS and __COLORS are constant variables I have kept the name of the variable in CAPTITAL letters but in the property function I have a function name CARDS and a function named COLORS so according to pep8 a function name should be in lowercase characters but I am confused that should I keep the name of the function in lowercase or should I keep the function name in capital letters as the functions CARDS, COLORS are not function but are properties of the class

Comment: I haven't read the styling guide but my IDE automatically tells me when I am not following it, and from that I can suggest you to keep it in lowercase.

Comment: ok what ide are you using pycharm?

Comment: Yes I am using pycharm.

Comment: Ok Thanks For Your Help

Answer (score 0):

[pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id35) don't specify this, but usually:

property in lowercase,
constant attributes can be in uppercase, but with no prefixes or [protected](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/protected-variable-in-python/) notation.
Maybe these constants may be defined at the module level.

something like this

class Card:

```
_CARDS = ["3"]
_COLORS = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow"]

@property
def cards(self) -> list:
    return self._CARDS

@property
def cards(self) -> list:
    return self._COLORS
```